# If $p+q+r=0$, prove these determinants are equal

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $p+q+r=0$, prove that

$$\begin{vmatrix}
pa&qb&rc\\
qc&ra&pb\\
rb&pc&qa
\end{vmatrix}=pqr\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c\\
c&a&b\\
b&c&a
\end{vmatrix}$$

My attempt is as follows:-

Taking $p$ common from first row, $q$ from second row and $r$ from third row

$$pqr\begin{vmatrix}
a&\dfrac{qb}{p}&\dfrac{rc}{p}\\
c&\dfrac{ra}{q}&\dfrac{pb}{q}\\
b&\dfrac{pc}{r}&\dfrac{qa}{r}
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$pqr\begin{vmatrix}
a&\dfrac{-bp-br}{p}&\dfrac{-cp-cq}{p}\\
c&\dfrac{-pa-qa}{q}&\dfrac{-qb-rb}{q}\\
b&\dfrac{-qc-rc}{r}&\dfrac{-pa-ra}{r}
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$pqr\begin{vmatrix}
a&-b-\dfrac{br}{p}&-c-\dfrac{cq}{p}\\
c&-a-\dfrac{pa}{q}&-b-\dfrac{rb}{q}\\
b&-c-\dfrac{qc}{r}&-a-\dfrac{pa}{r}
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$pqr\begin{vmatrix}
a&b+\dfrac{br}{p}&c+\dfrac{cq}{p}\\
c&a+\dfrac{pa}{q}&b+\dfrac{rb}{q}\\
b&c+\dfrac{qc}{r}&a+\dfrac{pa}{r}
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$pqr\left(\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c\\
c&a&b\\
b&c&a\end{vmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}
a&\dfrac{br}{p}&c\\
c&\dfrac{pa}{q}&b\\
b&\dfrac{qc}{r}&a\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&\dfrac{cq}{p}\\
c&a&\dfrac{rb}{q}\\
b&c&\dfrac{pa}{r}
\end{vmatrix}
\right)
$$

$$\left(pqr\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c\\
c&a&b\\
b&c&a\end{vmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}
pa&br&pc\\
qc&pa&qb\\
rb&qc&ra\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
pa&pb&cq\\
qc&qa&rb\\
rb&rc&pa
\end{vmatrix}
\right)
$$

Now I am left with two other determinants and their sum should come out zero.

I am getting no way to simplify those determinants, if you open those determinants, expression would be quite large.

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: over there, they have applied cramer's rule, without that also I came close but then expanding those two determinants is like hell, can we do it without cramer's rule.

Comment: What is wrong about using Sarrus?